# SWI-Prolog: [FATAL ERROR: Could not find system resources]

Tags: python, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to execute my Python script in which I use Prolog. The code is the following:

```
from pyswip import Prolog
prolog = Prolog()
prolog.consult("KB.pl")
print(list(prolog.query("faster(cat, dog)")))
```

I kept having the following error: SWI-Prolog: [FATAL ERROR: Could not find system resources].

I already tried to fix the issue following the instructions provided by SWI Prolog documentation.

- libswipl.dll is in the installation tree;
- bin directory of the installation tree is added to %PATH%.

I also tried to set the environment variable SWI_HOME_DIR from the Windows cmd using the following command line:

```
setx SWI_HOME_DIR "C:\Program Files\swipl"
```

Comment: are simple queries working? try `member(X, [1, 2, 3, 4])`.

Comment: If you try to collect all solutions to a query, it might blow the stack. That could also be the cause of the error. will `faster` predicate always terminate?